# Sign in Issues with SkyDrive API for Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, onedrive, live-sdk

I am creating a WP7 app with SkyDrive Access to it. I am using the SkyDrive API for it. When I am trying to login, it is showing 'Inalid Request' Error. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```csharp
    private void login_Click()
    {
        LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient("signInButton1.ClientId");
        auth.LoginCompleted +=
        new EventHandler<LoginCompletedEventArgs>(MoreScopes_LoginCompleted);
        auth.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update " });
    }

    void MoreScopes_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            LiveConnectSession session = e.Session;
            LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Signed in.";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            infoTextBlock.Text = "Error signing in: " + e.Error.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void signInButton1_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        login_Click();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this:

    LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient("signInButton1.ClientId");

it should be:

    LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient(signInButton1.ClientId);
```